# What is a programmatic way to delete all AWS resources associated with the DataBricks get started/tutorials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scripting, databricks

I've noticed that when completing [that content](https://docs.databricks.com/getting-started/tutorials/index.html) and then deleting the workspace from within the Databricks interface, there are still leftover AWS resources like a VPC, NAT gateway, etc.

What's the best way to ensure all of these are removed and unnecessary costs are avoided? Is there a template to do so? Some Terraform or Python snippet that can do the trick?

Thanks

Just going through the AWS web interface and deleting manually is obviously an option, I am asking for an automated means

Comment: On possible answer is to use [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke)

Comment: Terraform will only delete the resources if you created them with Terraform. If you run `aws-nuke` it will delete everything in the AWS account, not just these resources. If you have other things in the account, don't run `aws-nuke`. The most fool-proof way to do this without deleting other things would be to go through the tutorial again, but this time simply delete everything it told you to create.

Answer (score 0):

Are the resources tagged by Databricks on creation?  You could find a list of all the resources with that tag, and then remove them...

You could also look at building some automation around removing unused AWS resources.  I work on an [Open source project](https://github.com/unskript/Awesome-CloudOps-Automation) that has built some automations that could help:

[Release Unattached AWS Elastic IPs](https://github.com/unskript/Awesome-CloudOps-Automation/tree/master/AWS/Release_Unattached_AWS_Elastic_IPs.ipynb)

[Delete Unused AWS NAT Gateways](https://github.com/unskript/Awesome-CloudOps-Automation/tree/master/AWS/Delete_Unused_AWS_NAT_Gateways.ipynb)